# React-Native, how to access object attributes with a external variable?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables,
`currencies = {AUD": 1.5573, "BGN": 1.9558, "BRL": 6.4771, "CAD": 1.5304, ...`, and `selection`, which is a variable that contains one of these currency-codes. What is the best way to retrieve values with selection a-la `currencies.selection`, which doesn't work because the object has no attribute with such name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a object attribute like `object[attribute]` instead of `object.attribute`

```js
let currencies = {"AUD": 1.5573, "BGN": 1.9558, "BRL": 6.4771, "CAD": 1.5304},
        selection = "BRL"
    
console.log(currencies[selection])
```